# Getting error while creating new int[]{} in listview

Tags: android

I am getting an error while creating integer array:

`mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.lv_layout,null,new String[] { "name","photo","details"},new int[]{R.id.tv_name,R.id.iv_photo,R.id.tv_details}, 0);`

My code:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    MatrixCursor mMatrixCursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // The contacts from the contacts content provider is stored in this cursor
        mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id","name","photo","details"} );

        // Adapter to set data in the listview
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.lv_layout,null,new String[] { "name","photo","details"},new int[]{R.id.tv_name,R.id.iv_photo,R.id.tv_details}, 0);

        // Getting reference to listview
        ListView lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);

        // Setting the adapter to listview
        lstContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Creating an AsyncTask object to retrieve and load listview with contacts
        ListViewContactsLoader listViewContactsLoader = new ListViewContactsLoader();

        // Starting the AsyncTask process to retrieve and load listview with contacts
        listViewContactsLoader.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: what error r u getting?

Comment: If your app crashes then post your full stack trace copy from logcat with exception.

Comment: You might check your lv_layout.xml; make sure the TextView ids are correct. Is the middle one supposed to be R.id.iv_photo? Or R.id.tv_photo.

Comment: mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.lv_layout,null,new String[] { "name","photo","details"},new int[]{R.id.tv_name,R.id.iv_photo,R.id.tv_details}, 0); six parameters for SimpleCursorAdapter its looks like **SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, from, to)**